# How do I view the user error log for Azure Service Bus?

Tags: azureservicebus

I'm struggling to figure out how to diagnose reported user errors that are depicted in my Azure Service Bus metrics.

1. I first searched for errors in each of my console windows that Visual Studio launches as a result of running Azure Functions locally. **No errors were identified in the console windows**.
2. I attempted to follow the [instructions referenced in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-diagnostic-logs#enable-operational-logs) by navigating to ***Monitoring*** -> ***Diagnostic Settings***.
3. From there, I added a diagnostic setting and pointed to my designated storage account for archiving error logs.
4. I then launched the **Storage Explorer app** and searched through the various tables with no success.
5. I also launched Azure Service Bus Explorer. However, I was unable to identify a method for retrieving logs.

In conclusion, I don't know how to diagnose user errors that are depicted in my Azure Service Bus metrics.

**UPDATE:**

I reviewed my console windows that were launched from my local Azure functions and saw the error after scrolling.

Comment: Based on this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/resource-logs-collect-storage, I believe the data is stored in blob storage. You may want to look under blob containers :).

Comment: Guarav is right I believe. But just for clarity - what is a "user error"?

Comment: @GauravMantri - Thanks. I checked out my blob containers but was unable to identify any error logs.

Comment: @IsaacAbraham - "user errors" is the name that's displayed in the Azure Service Bus metrics chart for Queues and Topics.

Comment: UPDATE: I reviewed my console windows that were launched from my local Azure functions and saw the error after scrolling.